# What is the meaning of "B is a bialgebra covariantly acting on A"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $A$ be an algebra and $B$ a bialgebra. What is the meaning of "covariantly" in "B is covariantly acting on A"? Thank you very much.

Edit: it is on line 13 of the abstract of [the file](http://www.birs.ca/workshops/2015/15w5053/Programme15w5053.pdf) (page 3).

Comment: Probably, that $A$ is a $B$-module algebra. One can only guess, thuugh, if you do not provide context.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, thank you very much. I have edited the post.